Adding campaign block to product page [Magento 2.0]
Whenever we're doing campaigns on our eshop we usually add campaign information on each SKU product page with URL re-directing traffic to our campaign deals page as well. The problem is that it becomes very time consuming and complicated when we're doing several campaigns at the same time.
Our current workflow is that we setup html-code and upload it to each SKU through bulk-upload inside Magento.
Example of a campaign:
https://estore.asus.com/se/proart-px13-hn7306.html

But it would save us a lot of time if it was possible to create a block of this and just add this to the product page on relevant campaign SKUs. Is this possible somehow?

Hi @bitzz_ , product SKU you want to pass dynamically right?? or the code is static for all the product?

if you create a block and add it to the product page then on all PDP pages the content will be the same.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@JigsParmar So I actually tried to create a block of HTML in Content > Elements > Blocks > Add new Block and then I created a HTML block with the img, url and copy. I then went to Products > Searched one of my products > Content > Edit with Page Builder > Add content > Dynamic Block > and then selected the block I created. Unfortunately nothing happened. The blocks I want to add are static but different for different products. E.g., "Summer Sale Block", "Added value Block" or "Outlet" etc.

@blitzz_
You Need to create 1 static block and add it to product page using Widget

Create static block
go to content - > widget -> Add widget

choose option as shown in the below screenshots



Thank You!
